# Is there a way to reverse the MNIST?

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, j#

I have recently been looking into AI and the MNIST detest.  I have decided to create 18 different images in microsoft paint.  These images are 28x28, and are named accordingly into the code below.  I wanted to see if I could get my network to overfit on a certain set of images in hopes that I can prompt it with the label and have it return the image.

I would give it [[7]], and have it return a 28x28 array of numbers from 1 - 255 denoting the color of the pixel.  The only problem is that the network basically doesn't learn.  I have also tried putting it in the normal way.  I have given it the picture, just like the mnist, and had it return the data of the label.  It couldn't even to this.  I have the data scaled from 0 - 1 in this network.  If anyone can give any imput, that would be great.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib as plt
import os
from PIL import Image 

X = np.array([[0.01],[0.02],[0.03],[0.04],[0.05],[0.06],[0.07],[0.08],[0.9],[0.10],[0.11],[0.12],[0.13],[0.14],[0.23],[0.57],[0.64],[0.01]])
#X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 1+18 - 1))
print(np.shape(X))
Y = np.array([[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/one.png")[:,:,0]], [cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Two.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Three.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Four.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Five.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Six.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Seven.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Eight.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Nine.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Ten.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Eleven.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Twelve.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Thirteen.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Fourteen.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/23.png")[:,:,0]],[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/57.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/64.png")[:,:,0]],
[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/one.png")[:,:,0]]])
Y = np.reshape(Y, (18, 28, 28))
Y = np.reshape(Y, (18, 784))
print(Y)
print(np.shape(Y))
#Y = np.invert(np.array([Y]))
# = np.reshape(Y, (18, 784))
print(Y[1])
Image.fromarray(np.reshape(Y[1], (28, 28))).show()
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(units = (28, 28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1280, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2560, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2560, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2560, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2560, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 7840, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 784, activation = 'relu'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 1000)
img = [[cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Three.png")[:,:,0]]]  
print(np.shape(img))
img = np.reshape(img, (1, 784))
#img = np.reshape(img, (18, 28, 28))
#img = np.reshape(img, (18, 784))
#im = np.reshape(im, (28, 28))
#img.save('my.png')
#print(model.predict([[img]]))
print(model.predict([[0.09]]))

#img.show()
#model.predict(cv2.imread("C:/Users/17324/Downloads/aiFlow/Eight.png"))
```

Here is what the output looks like.

```
Epoch 999/1000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 262ms/step - loss: 1399771.7500 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1000/1000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 256ms/step - loss: 1399771.7500 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
(1, 1, 28, 28)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 326ms/step
[[199282.06  199288.88  199315.81  199300.83       0.    199299.22
  199265.17  199350.97  199292.02  199304.56  199288.55  199294.83
  199289.64  199299.23  199297.22       0.    199309.2   199306.39
  199298.88  199364.98  199311.77  199319.39  199301.73  199300.73
       0.    199309.02       0.         0.    199326.27  199319.03
  199299.25  199312.         0.    199290.66  199312.22       0.
       0.    199294.34  199302.16  199316.95  199396.31  199282.86
       0.    199297.58  199278.92  199348.81  199289.9   199282.81
       0.    199356.6        0.    199288.1   199292.84  199300.83
  199301.39  199299.83       0.    199278.77  199318.38  199301.17
  199326.14  199281.9        0.    199307.53       0.         0.
  199331.94  199295.22  199295.66  199253.81       0.    199306.03
  199320.08  199302.05  199301.53  199274.25       0.    199289.84
  199304.66  199311.42  199294.4   199280.39       0.    199295.4
  199288.52  199286.2        0.         0.    190980.31  195136.56
  199328.12  199294.19  196189.23  189574.28  185125.86  178575.97
  177170.53  177145.08       0.    177149.14  179951.61  190983.16
       0.    199294.06  199298.94  199303.94  199271.25  199295.3
  199308.17  199301.11  199301.34  199317.2   199316.45  199291.19
  199312.8   189280.36       0.    152979.77  153675.66  159425.44
  147432.53  143942.23       0.         0.    127356.23  125194.97
  128731.125 143976.19  164658.25       0.    185449.77       0.
  191019.52  195172.84  199345.67  199319.1   199328.34  199310.11
  199326.72  199298.78  199268.34  199284.75  199248.98  188257.53
  154988.52  110339.97  108355.984 110099.92  132865.7   123508.63
       0.     87205.01   96845.234  91384.75  107316.375      0.
       0.    154964.05  130471.39  134176.8   161948.17  166444.45
  174034.58  170300.36  181345.98  195137.61  199316.45  199283.16
  199313.52  199293.86  199283.97  188174.39       0.     87873.31
   89591.49   95854.234 119326.17  101727.664 101038.61   93777.21
       0.         0.    110745.26  119310.08  105236.75       0.
  102418.36       0.    151198.75       0.    167122.44  166133.92
  166776.1   184403.25       0.         0.    199305.39  199359.05
       0.    178494.16       0.         0.     75068.34       0.
       0.    110044.23       0.    106530.07   89276.71       0.
  107541.33  127003.96  107611.13   77874.125  80225.92   80943.51
  138736.69       0.    166142.69  166099.33  166120.39  177534.36
  199300.33  199299.16  199271.84  199319.77  189268.98  177449.89
       0.    111370.75   58839.445  83024.27  104164.52  129708.21
       0.         0.    101348.93       0.    107920.38       0.
       0.         0.     77496.53       0.    136696.2   184012.34
       0.    166099.38       0.         0.    199322.16  199275.78
  199289.88       0.         0.         0.         0.    121811.7
   72026.87       0.         0.         0.    135331.5        0.
       0.    118669.38  121786.58       0.         0.     85833.74
   75445.95   99653.39       0.    166042.48       0.         0.
       0.    177132.1   199294.84  199243.56       0.    189256.23
  188233.28  188241.77  132855.89       0.     95098.125 101292.125
  121157.65       0.         0.    113823.55  111694.23  111779.91
       0.    141794.56       0.    122496.66   93049.22   99661.66
  123181.44  145282.7   158796.56  155006.27       0.    177518.39
  199331.9   199326.8   196170.06       0.         0.    188281.98
  137700.4   132845.42  111051.555 130080.83  128365.89  143903.88
  123481.02  101396.83  117664.79  112747.21  128726.805 118659.72
       0.         0.     94017.59       0.    111106.71  128703.734
       0.         0.    159493.67  177484.92  199297.69  199319.84
  189261.69  188233.02  188230.73  188207.28  146640.47       0.
  102352.13       0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  122128.44       0.         0.    126608.17  134312.72       0.
   88990.49       0.         0.    115554.06  143876.56  157792.31
  166095.27       0.    199305.6   199321.42  188231.62  188229.97
  185115.3   179594.12  133575.97  116597.43   91000.64  117601.586
       0.    120066.92  102458.055 111036.39  118728.99  124910.44
  122199.02  107257.555 117640.99   96140.84       0.     88560.375
       0.    121800.93  154977.12  166406.3   172991.95  188579.89
  195167.72  199291.38       0.    185075.92       0.    174015.48
       0.    112057.375      0.         0.         0.         0.
       0.     92730.22  106510.62       0.    119710.516      0.
  122145.17  121087.07       0.    106523.766      0.    116679.51
  155370.14  166059.9        0.    184054.98       0.         0.
  194086.02  178170.9   177151.56  163949.38       0.         0.
   79940.23  106829.766      0.    108942.445      0.     94069.695
   97273.63       0.    110720.35  110074.805      0.         0.
  101049.61       0.         0.    136707.17  155359.36       0.
  177152.95  177485.73  192764.16  199298.95  199330.53  177155.78
       0.    156036.77  134560.81       0.     83391.04       0.
       0.    101715.32       0.         0.     89650.375 111056.54
  114484.59  119046.85  121110.24  131135.8   102719.766 106893.805
  130792.61       0.         0.    161915.95  188256.89  188248.83
  199295.78  199316.97  199290.12  177846.8        0.    155011.12
  133207.88  132873.95  106923.89  121442.3        0.         0.
  127696.24       0.     98617.73  107628.79       0.    111076.36
  122151.36  118343.68       0.         0.    119007.69       0.
  151541.23  159865.77  188194.73  188205.42       0.    199295.36
  199276.1   188914.53  177163.3   155026.53  132892.56       0.
       0.    110665.51       0.         0.    121798.516 115246.49
       0.    110733.61  116568.36       0.    119391.94  111033.2
   95464.4    94086.45  116641.3   143891.66  144282.92  170555.77
  188201.12  192743.14  199276.38  199279.12  199274.8   199303.8
  188551.16  166768.1   143942.05  126618.04   86489.24       0.
       0.    106557.4   115288.    116584.61       0.         0.
  139817.75  144969.05       0.    121783.12   99998.91  103836.14
  127651.69       0.    157489.31  181687.67  192741.05  199293.9
  199278.8   199320.23  199324.1   199279.97       0.         0.
  122143.69   98675.27   86790.7   102431.4   100333.49   93424.05
       0.    114570.055 143202.4        0.    138754.5   144661.77
       0.    134228.92       0.         0.    143910.22       0.
  177145.28  192744.34  199300.58       0.    199296.11  199309.8
  199280.16  199333.6        0.         0.         0.    122487.71
  104800.29  105194.4        0.         0.    132829.69  144980.12
  172970.45       0.    177155.58  174024.9   155692.92  143930.77
  143223.83  147744.58       0.    181694.44  192733.56       0.
       0.    199292.4        0.    199284.64       0.    199308.11
  188904.86  177151.52       0.    155311.94  149808.52  139069.5
       0.    143996.98       0.         0.    155029.1   149805.77
       0.    157768.78       0.    170618.42  166424.67  177121.16
  177169.7   192691.36  199284.88  199332.94  199325.03  199283.77
  199290.02       0.    199297.08  199276.08  199280.7   199260.83
  183638.55       0.    159523.86  165439.27  160878.25  159532.8
       0.    166127.88  166065.23  166092.         0.    155047.64
  155034.47  157821.42       0.    181733.8   192740.12  199314.39
  199290.89  199343.94  199293.12       0.    199230.34  199275.95
  199292.58  199295.38  199331.81  199263.84  199310.98  199292.9
  199314.97  199310.86  188835.44  177176.9   171974.3   166116.88
       0.    166077.66       0.         0.    166060.02  170609.36
  177801.81  199309.22  199271.34  199296.33  199299.78       0.
  199285.78  199280.83  199302.1        0.    199310.25  199299.77
  199330.94  199344.62       0.    199295.17  199275.64  199313.84
  199253.67  199300.25  199304.55  199288.64  199301.17  188884.1
  177121.34  177153.11       0.    177132.86       0.    199283.19
  199256.03       0.    199317.48  199289.95  199270.36  199283.28
  199297.53       0.         0.    199296.03  199302.28  199358.78
  199319.67  199310.56  199309.67  199271.89  199297.53  199305.5
  199301.12       0.    199309.16  199363.48  199308.92  199300.34
  199272.8        0.    199269.58  199265.88  199278.77  199324.14
       0.    199297.64  199331.98  199325.75       0.    199324.12
  199294.81  199289.08  199270.95  199322.05  199295.14       0.
  199300.19  199258.08  199314.14  199310.08  199315.92       0.
  199299.31  199298.56  199375.52  199290.88  199288.38  199311.53
  199289.39  199322.83  199302.05  199373.31  199284.28  199314.86
  199288.2   199317.53  199305.3   199313.55 ]]
```

Notice how the accuracy is really low.  The network is also outputting numbers waaaaaay above 255. Even when I switch the labels and use a sigmoid, it deosnt' work.

Please note that I have tried playing around with the loss and optimizer.  These combinations were the ones that I could get the most out of, not that they actually produced something worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Through testing, here is what I have found.  Basically, we need to use mse and train over 2000 epochs.  This was found through testing different scaling of the data.  The data doesn't need to be scaled.